# PhpExcel how to turn off the default conversion of numbers to scientific notation

Tags: php, phpexcel

How to turn off the default conversion of numbers to scientific notation. When importing from an excel file, large numbers are automatically converted to scientific notation (3.5868405364945E+14 it should be:358684053649447).Is there any option to turn off conversion in PhpExcel?
Or reverse conversions from PHP? When I trying to use printf,

```
printf("%d", "3.5868405364945E+14"); // 358684053649450 wrong value
```

final number is inaccurate.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, you'll never get the full value again, it's been already rounded, because your number has 16 digits and **15 digits is the limit for numbers in Excel**.

It happens at the entry point, when you enter a number that excedes 15 digits. EXcel will round it, modifying your entry forever.

It's similar as storing a decimal number like 1.2 as integer, you'll loose that 0.2, no matter what you do, it will be 1 forever.

The only solution for this is (too late in your case), **storing the large number as text** in the first place, just adding a single quote before the number: `'358684053649447` instead of `358684053649447`. Excel will interpret that as string, not as number, and you'll be able to save numbers higher than 15 digits.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Unfortunately, I have no influence on the data contained in the excel file. Is there any possibility of dealing with this problem during or after import?

Comment: Hi. If this answer satisfied the question, please mark it as best answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the number format before reading the formatted value.

```
$cell = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell("A1");
$cell->getStyle()->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(\PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_NUMBER);
echo $cell->getFormattedValue();
```